# Pre-built version of pkg could not be found on your system FreeBSD - AMD 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, freebsd

I am trying to install `nano` on FreeBSD using the pkg, but whenever I try to install it by using

```
pkg install nano
```

I get an error that says

> pkg: Error fetching http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:12:x86:64/latest/Latest/pkg.txz: Non-recoverable resolver failure A pre-built version of pkg could not be found for your system Consider changing PACKAGESITE or install it from ports: 'ports-mgmt/pkg'

I can't find any reason why that's happening and any fixes to that.
My architecture is 64-bit and the output of `uname -a` is

> FreeBSD caleb@taylor.com 12.0-RELEASE FreBSD 12.0-RELEASE r3416664

Comment: I incorporated your answers into the question.

Comment: `Non-recoverable resolver failure`  As @arrowd says, you need to set up DNS.

Comment: I encountered this on FreeNAS 11.2 by failing to check VNET during jail creation, resulting in a jail with no network access

Answer (score 2):

By default, FreeBSD ships `pkg` bootstrap executable that fetches real `pkg` program. Your error seems to originate from wrongly configured DNS.

Check that your system can resolve DNS names:

```
# host google.com
# host pkg.freebsd.org
```

If it doesn't work, check `/etc/resolv.conf` file.